# How do I embed an angular 6 component inside of a web component inside of an angular 6 app

Tags: angular, web-component

I would like to build a table web component which adds some functionality onto the basic html5 table tag.

I would like to do this with web-components so that it will be reusable across apps which do not use angular.

However, I would also like to build the table to allow for custom cell components which are written in the consuming angular app.

Is this possible/what's the suggested way of doing this?

Intuitively, I'd like to just add a tag to the dom, but it seems expensive for Angular to be watching for changes and running lifecycle hooks when it recognizes a new component tag-- is there a way to get angular to watch for subTree changes on the node with my web-component?

Thanks so much in advance, I couldn't find any info on this.

I'm using Stencil to write my web-component.

Comment: wonder what's your progress on this. I am investigating how to embed a React component inside of stencil web component as a PoC of an app having existing library of small React components